# Weird JS Behaviour: Additional line is needed to execute function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, console

I just don't get it.

```
function init() {

    $(document).on('click', '#listFilter .option:not(".darr"), #listSort .option:not(".darr")', function() {
        var selected = $(this).data('ajax-link'),
            dropDown = $(this).parent().parent(),
            filter = '',
            sort = '';

        if ( dropDown.attr('id') == "weaveListFilter" ) {
            filter = selected;
            sort = $('#listSort .darr').data('ajax-link');
        } else if ( dropDown.attr('id') == "weaveListSort" ) {
            filter = $('#listFilter .darr').data('ajax-link');
            sort = selected;
        }

        if ( selected != dropDown.find('.darr').data('ajax-link') )
            console.log('why?')
            sortList(filter, sort, dropDown.parent());
            //console.log('wtf!')
    });

}
```

Without the `console.log('why?')` the `sortList()` function is not called!!!
Why does it not get called without this line?

The weirdest thing is, that this "why?" is not even logged in my console. But without it the sortList() function doesn't execute. The "wtf!" after the function-call would be logged but I don't get it anyway.

Ideas? Am I dumb or so?

Comment: Are there any JS errors in the error console?

Comment: It sounds like the condition `selected != dropDown.find('.darr').data('ajax-link')` is never true.  If nothing gets logged, then `console.log('why?')` is never executed, either.  Try surrounding the `console.log` call and `sortList` with `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `if` is failing. There are no braces `{ }` around the `if` body, so only the first statement is considered part of the `if`. By adding the `console.log`, you are making the `sortList` no longer part of the `if`.

First, put braces around your `if`:

```
if ( selected != dropDown.find('.darr').data('ajax-link') ) {
    sortList(filter, sort, dropDown.parent());
}
```

Then go find out why your `if` clause is failing.

Comment: Isn't it possible to neglect the {} brackets? If it's intended correctly?

Comment: yes, it is, but it is cases like this that makes it helpful to have them, so that mistakes are not made.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the block `{ }` after this `if`:

```
if ( selected != dropDown.find('.darr').data('ajax-link') )
```

This condition is apparently false, so what happens is:

- `console.log()` doesn't execute
- `sortList()` is not attached to the `if`, so it always runs.

If you comment `console.log()` out, neither of the statements runs, because

- `console.log()` is commented
- `sortList()` is under a false condition